# Is Visual Studio Development Server producing log files?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7

I'm running Visual Studio Development Server on Windows 7. Is it producing log files? If so, where?

Comment: Are you looking for something particular in the log files, or are just wondered what kind of stuff it might be logging?

Comment: I have code that makes specific LogAppend calls that i'd like to verify before uploading to IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need log files, just use IIS. I think Cassini does not produce log files.